# Text formating depending on conditions

Tags: conditionals, programming, expl3

I have some conditions which are stored in boolean variables, such as

```
\bool_new:N \l_word_numbered_bool
\bool_new:N \l_word_lowercase_bool
\bool_new:N \l_word_centering_bool
```

I need to format words (or paragraphs) depending on the values of the boolean variables in the simplest possible way.

The first thing that comes to mind is to use many `\bool_if:NTF`-s but I think there should be a simpler way.

My ultimate goal is to create a custom view of the section.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xtemplate,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareObjectType { sectioning } { 1 }

\DeclareTemplateInterface{sectioning}{section}{1}
{
    numbered : boolean = true ,
    space-above : length  = 2ex ,
    space-below : length  = 2ex ,
    font-shape : choice {italic, slanted, normal} = normal,
    lowercase : choice {true, false} = true,
    centering : choice{true, false} = false,
    font-weight : choice {bold, normal} = bold,
    font-color : tokenlist,
    font-size : length = 12pt,
    %font-face : tokenlist,
}
% the interface for the template `initial':

% variables first:
\bool_new:N \l_sectioning_numbered_bool
\dim_new:N \l_sectioning_space_above_dim
\dim_new:N \l_sectioning_space_below_dim
\bool_new:N \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sectioning_centering_bool
\dim_new:N \l_font_size_dim


\DeclareTemplateCode {sectioning} {section} {1}
{
    numbered        =           \l_sectioning_numbered_bool ,
    font-size       =           \l_font_size_dim,
    lowercase       =           {
        true        =           \bool_set_true:N \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool,
        false       =           \bool_set_false:N \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool,
    },

    centering       =           {
        true        =           \bool_set_true:N \l_sectioning_centering_bool,
        false       =           \bool_set_false:N \l_sectioning_centering_bool,
    },


    space-above     =           \l_sectioning_space_above_dim ,
    space-below     =           \l_sectioning_space_below_dim ,
    font-shape      = {
        italic      =           \cs_set_nopar:Nn \afontshape: {\itshape},
        slanted     =           \cs_set_nopar:Nn \afontshape: {\itshape},
        normal      =           \cs_set_nopar:Nn \afontshape: {\upshape},
    },
    font-weight     = {
        bold        =           \cs_set_nopar:Nn \afontseries: {\bfseries},
        normal      =           \cs_set_nopar:Nn \afontseries: {\rmfamily},
    },
    %font-face      =           \l_font_tl,
    font-color      =           \l_tmpa_tl, 
}
{
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \vskip\l_sectioning_space_above_dim
      \group_begin:
      \color\l_tmpa_tl
      %\cs:w \l_font_tl \cs_end: 
      \fontsize{\l_font_size_dim}{\l_font_size_dim}\afontseries:\afontshape:\selectfont 
      \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool {
      \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_numbered_bool {\thesection.\, \tl_to_lowercase:n {#1}}{\tl_to_lowercase:n {#1}}
    }
    {
        \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_numbered_bool {\thesection.\, \tl_to_uppercase:n {#1}}{\tl_to_uppercase:n {#1}}
    }

      \group_end:
      \addtocounter{section}{1}
    \vskip\l_sectioning_space_below_dim
}


% a few instances, starting with `fullname':
\DeclareInstance {sectioning}{standart}{section}
{
    numbered    =   true,
    font-shape  =   italic,
    font-weight =   bold,
    lowercase   =   true,
    space-below =   2em,
    %font-face  =   arial,
    font-size = 12 pt
}


% the user command:
\DeclareDocumentCommand \sectant{m}
{
\UseInstance{sectioning}{standart}{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sectant{Something}



\end{document}
```

Depending on the values within

```
\DeclareInstance {sectioning}{standart}{section}
{
    numbered    =   false,
    font-shape  =   italic,
    font-weight =   bold,
    lowercase   =   false,
    space-below =   2em,
    %font-face  =   arial,
}
```

I expect the desired formating of `\sectant{Something}`. My MWE is workable, but as you can see below the part of check code for `upper/lower` case and `numbered/unnumbered` look very terrible.

```
  \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_numbered_bool {\thesection.\, \tl_to_lowercase:n {#1}}{\tl_to_lowercase:n {#1}}
}
{
    \bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_numbered_bool {\thesection.\, \tl_to_uppercase:n {#1}}{\tl_to_uppercase:n {#1}}
}
```

Comment: I think you have to give us more. What exactly are you looking for? Write an example, or explain a little more what you want to achieve. Remember you also have `\bool_if:nTF`.

Comment: @Manuel I've added MWE.

Comment: I don't see yet what exactly are you looking for. What's the problem with `\bool_if:NT \l_sectioning_numbered_bool { <formatted number> }`? If the problem is *mixing* various bools you have `\bool_if:nTF`. In my opinion you should be more concise and add details. Right now, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Manuel At the end of the post I've highlight a problem. For checking key values of lowercase and numbered my code using \bool_if:NTF does not look laconic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\bool_if:NT \l_sectioning_numbered_bool { \thesection.\ }
\bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool
 { \text_lowercase:n } { \text_uppercase:n } { #1 }
```

In that case, I think that would be enough. May be clearer is

```
\bool_if:NT \l_sectioning_numbered_bool { \thesection.\ }
\bool_if:NTF \l_sectioning_lowercase_bool
 { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
 { \text_uppercase:n { #1 } }
```

The last bool, could be in other cases, even done with (notice I shortened the name just to fit it into one line)

```
\use:c { text_ \bool_if:NTF \l_sect_lower_bool { lower } { upper } case:n } { #1 }
```

A thin I've seen you haven't done is add the name of the “package” to your definitions. For example they could carry `sk` (sergiokapone)

```
\bool_new:N \l_sk_sectioning_numbered_bool
\dim_new:N \l_sk_sectioning_space_above_dim
\dim_new:N \l_sk_sectioning_space_below_dim
\bool_new:N \l_sk_sectioning_lowercase_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sk_sectioning_centering_bool
\dim_new:N \l_sk_font_size_dim
```